# Why does send() in client application block when server is terminated?

Tags: windows, sockets, winsock, winsock2

I have a server application and a client application (localhost, loopback) which exchange data with each other via **sockets**.

When I shutdown the server (console) application (via <`Ctrl C`>) I expect the `send()` or `recv()` calls made in the client application to return with an error.

I observe exactly this behaviour on Linux, however after following the same steps on Windows the application hangs indefinitely at `send()`.

What is the reason for this?
How do I ensure that the application is able to detect that the remote connection is closed, in a clean way?

More diagnostics information:

When both the server and client are running I execute `netstat -a -o -n -b` 
    and I am able to observe both the client and server socket in **ESTABLISHED** state. 
    However after terminating the server program when I run `netstat -a -o -n -b`
    I am not able to see even the client program socket in the list of network connections.

Comment: TCP does not guarantee that you will be able to detect a broken connection other than through a timeout. But I can't explain why this was the case here. Normally, TCP stacks act cooperatively and signal the other side that the connection is gone. Did you do anything to interrupt network connectivity?

Comment: @usr - You mean apart from aborting the server program with a < Ctrl-C >? If yes, then no.

Comment: Can you try capturing network packets on the machine where you abort? This should result in a RST being sent. If not that'S the explanation. What OS is this?

Comment: An *abnormal* socket closure cannot be detected in a timely manner without using timeouts. If the socket does not receive a `FIN` or `RST` from the remote side, it will think the connection is still valid. A blocking-mode socket will buffer sent data until the buffer fills up, then it will block until 1) the buffer is transmitted and acked to free buffer space, 2) a `FIN`/`RST` is received, or 3) the socket is closed locally. That is why your `send()` is blocking.

Comment: To avoid that blockage indefinitely, have a look at the `SO_SNDTIMEO` option of `setsockopt()`: "*The timeout, in milliseconds, for blocking send calls. The default for this option is zero, which indicates that a send operation will not time out. If a blocking send call times out, the connection is in an indeterminate state and should be closed.*"  Or else use your socket in non-blocking mode, and then use `select()` or equivalent to implement your own timeout.

Comment: I tried this with Cygwin on the same system (exact same code), and with Cygwin sockets too the client detects the untimely demise of the server. So, is this because the default configuration of sockets is different in Winsock in comparison to the Cygwin sockets library? Is that well within the realm of expectation or is something wrong with Winsock?